# Probability - Rule of multiplication. Am I applying it correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

am trying to solve following question and not sure I am doing it correct. I have provided answer to two questions here and my logic. Can someone please let me know if I am doing these right. The third question, I don't know how to do, any help will be much appreciated.

Assume the likelihood that any flight on an Airline arrives within 15 minutes of the scheduled time is 0.72. We select two flights from yesterday for study.

a. What is the likelihood all two of the selected flights arrived within 15 minutes of the scheduled time?
Answer: Since probably of one flight within 15 minutes is 0.72, for two flights will be 0.72*0.72

b. What is the likelihood that none of the selected flights arrived within 15 minutes of the scheduled time?
Answer: Probability for one flight arrival time not in 15 minutes is 1-0.72 = 0.28. Therefore for two flights it will be 0.28*0.28

c. What is the likelihood at least one of the selected flights did not arrive within 15 minutes of the scheduled time?
Answer: I am not sure how to solve this

Comment: Your answers to (a) and (b) are both correct *assuming* that flight's arrivals being on time are independent events.  In reality, this is a bad assumption since reasons for one flight to be delayed could very well affect the other flight's arrival time as well such as airport strikes or bad weather, etc...  The best answer is that there is not enough information, but the intended answer is that we assume independence and arrive at the answers that you had using the calculations that you had.

Comment: For (c), continuing the independence assumption, recognize that "*at least one of the flights did not arrive on the time*" is the opposite event of "*all flights did arrive on time.*"  You should remember that $Pr(A)+Pr(\text{not}~A) = 1$

Comment: The easiest way is simply 1 minus sum of the other two possibilities, since you now have covered all possibilities.

Comment: @herbsteinberg do not confuse the phrase "at least one" with the phrase "exactly one."  You only subtract one of the answers to the earlier parts of the question, not both.

Comment: i am confused with "at least" here. So its answer will be same as for (b) i.e., 0.28*0.28?

Comment: No.  For purposes of illustration, suppose the two flights in question are flights from **A**tlanta and **B**oston (*hereby shortened to just their initial letters, A and B*).  The possible outcomes are: **i)** A is on time and B is on time, **ii)** A is on time and B is late, **iii)** A is late and B is on time, **iv)** A is late and B is late.  The answer to part (a) is the probability of case **i)**.  The answer to part (b) is the probability of case **iv)**.  The answer to part (c) is the sum of the probabilities for cases **ii),iii),iv)**.

Comment: "at least one" means that it could be one or two the number of flights that arrive within 15 minutes. As pointed out by @JMoravitz, the answer is $1-0.28^2$, or $0.72^2+2(0.72)(0.28)$.

Comment: @RobertoCabal "*What is the likelihood at least one of the selected flights* **did not** *arrive within 15 minutes*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, my bad. In that case is $1-0.72^2$